# Installing expo-cli: Could not resolve dependency:

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: type-fest@0.5.2
npm ERR! node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/type-fest
npm ERR!   type-fest@"^0.5.2" from boxen@4.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/boxen
npm ERR!     boxen@"4.1.0" from expo-cli@4.4.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR!       expo-cli@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     boxen@"4.1.0" from xdl@59.0.37
npm ERR!     node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl
npm ERR!       xdl@"59.0.37" from expo-cli@4.4.7
npm ERR!       node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR!         expo-cli@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@expo/dev-tools)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional type-fest@"^0.13.1" from @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.3.3    
npm ERR! node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@"^0.3.3" from @expo/webpack-config@0.12.71   
npm ERR!   node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/webpack-config
npm ERR!     @expo/webpack-config@"0.12.71" from xdl@59.0.37
npm ERR!     node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl
npm ERR!       xdl@"59.0.37" from expo-cli@4.4.7
npm ERR!       node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR!       1 more (@expo/dev-tools)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried using `--force` but it didn't work. I also tried using `--legacy-peer-deps` and that made it install but when I type `expo init myapp` it says:

> `bash: expo: command not found`

What is the problem over here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but this command worked for me:

```
npm install --global expo-cli --legacy-peer-deps
```